# How to access Bootstrap-Dropdown-Elements with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am currently trying to access some textfields inside my bootstrap-dropdown menu inside a header partial and it seems that capybara does not find these elements. Here is my code, i really dont know what i am doing wrong :/

Here is my Dropdown Menu :

```
<li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Sign in <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

          <li><%= f.label :email %></li>
          <li><%= f.text_field :email %></li>
          <li><%= f.label :password %></li>
          <li><%= f.password_field :password %></li>
          <li><%= f.submit "Sign in",class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></li>

                          <% end %>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

This is my Utilitie Function where i wanna access the textfield:

```
include ApplicationHelper

    def sign_in(user, options={})
      if options[:no_capybara]
        # Sign in when not using Capybara.
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
      else
        visit root_url
        find("a.dropdown-toggle").click
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end
    end
```

And this is the error Message i got ..

```
Failure/Error: sign_in user
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:12:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: It worked for me(bootstrap3, capybara2.1). What version of bootstrap and capybara do you use? And do you run test as rack-test or selenium?

Comment: Same versions over here. I discovered that capybara just not found the fields when the dropdown element is included in my header partial. if i put the dropdown into my static page, the fields will be found .. very confusing to me. It seems that there is a problem with the header partial ..

Comment: I am running as rake test like so --> bundle exec rspec spec/

Comment: could you solve it? how?

Comment: I made this post 6 years ago. Sorry but I am not able to tell you want I actually did to make this work.